# Keras neural network multiple input/output

Tags: python-3.x, keras, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I want to create a Keras neural network in which there are multiple inputs and outputs (let's call *input1/input2* and *output1/output2*).

1. **Is it possible** to predict *output1* from *input1* and produce *output2* based and trained on *input2*?
2. Are there some constraints about the **size** of the inputs?

I'm asking it because there are no clues in keras documentation.

Comment: 1. yes it is possible. 2. What do you mean by constraint on size of input?

Comment: Sorry, I meant if  input1 size should be greater than input2 size or vice-versa.

Comment: No there is no such constraint.

Comment: Other then this, is there any specifics where you stuck at?

Comment: Not for now! Your answers were really helpful, thanks a lot!

Comment: This question is not about programming. For future questions that are similar, please ask at https://ai.stackexchange.com/. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to create a Model that takes multiple inputs and gives multiple outputs you can use the Keras Function API.

A simple example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

image_input=keras.Input(
    shape=(299,299,3),name="image_input"
)
meta_input=keras.Input(
    shape=(12,),name="image-meta_input" #input which contains data like age, date, size etc 
)

I=tf.keras.applications.InceptionV3(
    include_top=True, weights='imagenet', 
)(image_input)


c=layers.concatenate([meta_input,I])
x=layers.Dense(32,activation=keras.activations.relu)(c)
out2=layers.Dense(8,activation=keras.activations.softmax)(x) #multiclass
out1=layers.Dense(1,activation=keras.activations.sigmoid)(x)
model=keras.Model(
    inputs=[meta_input,image_input],
    outputs=[out1,out2]
)
```

You can plot the Model to visualize it:

```
keras.utils.plot_model(model,show_shapes=True)
```

[image]